# cgroups: throttle per user disk I/O bandwidth on Linux

Tags: cgroups

I have a Linux web server (Debian, just in case that made a difference), which is Apache + PHP-FPM. Each Apache `VirtualHost` uses a dedicated PHP-FPM pool (through a dedicated unix socket), which runs under a dedicated system user.

For example, let's say I have the example.com `VirtualHost`. Then, in the `VirtualHost` Apache config, I have something like

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm-examplecom.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/examplecom/htdocs/www.example.com/
```

And, in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/` I have the corresponding configuration file for the PHP-FPM pool, namely `examplecom.conf`, which contains

```
[examplecom]
user = examplecom
listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm-examplecom.sock
; and other things...
```

It happens, more often than not, some website gets hacked (forgot to update, installed shameless insecure plugins, you name it) and starts hogging available server resources: in my case hard disk I/O bandwidth is the most common.

In order to avoid DoS-ing all the websites on the same server, I'd like to limit the hard disk I/O bandwidth per website, so that a hacked website goes down alone and it does not take all the others with it.

How do I limit the hard disk I/O bandwidth per website? Well, I think I can limit that per user instead, since each `VirtualHost` has a dedicated user. And how do I do that? Well, Google suggested me cgroups.

However I couldn't find any example about how to add a *user*, instead of a process ID, to a control group.

Am I looking for the wrong thing? Or am I searching for the wrong keywords? I don't know, but the question is: how do I limit per user hard disk I/O bandwidth using cgroups under Linux?

Comment: The cgroups subsystem works on processes and threads. What you could do with cgroups is confining the processes/threads of a particular user to a particular cgroup. If your Apache+FPM configuration really uses PAM then you can do that through the PAM session configuration of your service, e.g. by using `pam_cgroup` or perhaps by using a `pam_exec` script that moves the processes into the cgroup they belong to. Then tune that cgroup's `blkio` (if you use cgroupsv1) or `io` (if you use cgroupsv2) controller. Dive into `man cgroups`.

Comment: You say "if it *really* uses PAM": that "*really*" makes me wonder if it is a strange thing. Doesn't the pool configuration I posted make PHP-FPM use PAM to switch to the specified user?

Comment: It's not strange at all, it's just that I know little about current Apache and nothing at all about PHP+FPM. To be honest I see nothing referring explicitly to PAM in that snippet but I trust you if you say it uses PAM under the hood.

Comment: No, please do not trust me, I'm not a reliable source in this case. I've used the "PAM user" expression as a synonym of "system user", but now I realize it was a bad idea. I'm going to edit my question and remove  PAM references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [LL3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/342404/ll3) comments to my question, I figured out I had to resort to a custom script. So here it is. It looks for the PHP-FPM processes, it takes respective running users and PIDs, it creates the `cgroups` and it inserts the PIDs in the correct `cgroups`.

Then I configured a `crontab` entry so that the script runs once per hour, which is more than enough in my case: Linux automatically puts child processes into the parent process `cgroup`, so this scripts actually needs to run only once just after every PHP-FPM restart (such as at boot time or when I add a new website/user). Running it once per hour it's useful to avoid forgetting to run it manually when it's due.

This script assumes the `/cgroups` directory was mounted with the `cgroup2` filesystem, so you should arrange for it beforehand. You can add an entry into `/etc/fstab` and, if your kernel mounts `cgroups` version 1 by default, configure `/etc/default/grub` to disable v1 and reboot (hint: add `cgroup_no_v1=all` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and then run `update-grub && reboot`).

It has been running in production for a month now and it seems to work. I'm pretty sure there are compromised websites at least in one of the two servers where I put this, and it does a good job in limiting the damages (unrelated sites go down only for a few seconds now and then).

Please note that, since the first version of this script, I had to edit it to make it monitor CPU and memory too, because monitoring disk I/O alone was not enough.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEVICE="254:0" # see /proc/partitions, this is /dev/vda in my case
WRITE_IOLIMIT=2097152 # 2MB/s, choose this as a fraction of your disk max write rate, I tested mine with `dd if=/dev/vda of=/testmaxspeed.dd bs=1M count=10000 status=progress`
READ_IOLIMIT=4194304 # 4MB/s, choose this as a fraction of your disk max read rate, I tested mine with `dd if=/dev/vda of=/dev/null bs=1M count=10000 status=progress`

function cleanup
{
  rm -f "$PLISTFILE" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

trap cleanup INT TERM EXIT

PLISTFILE=$(mktemp)

ps axo user:40,pid,comm | grep php-fpm | grep -v 'grep php-fpm' | grep -v '^root ' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 1-2 | sort | uniq > $PLISTFILE

cat $PLISTFILE | while read ROW ; do
  USERNAME=$(echo "$ROW" | cut -d' ' -f1)
  mkdir /cgroups/$USERNAME 2>/dev/null
  echo "$DEVICE rbps=$READ_IOLIMIT" > /cgroups/$USERNAME/io.max
  echo "$DEVICE wbps=$WRITE_IOLIMIT" > /cgroups/$USERNAME/io.max
  echo 402653184 > /cgroups/$USERNAME/memory.high # throttle when user is above 384MB of RAM
  echo 603979776 > /cgroups/$USERNAME/memory.max # OOM-Kill when user is above 576MB of RAM
done

echo "+io" > /cgroups/cgroup.subtree_control
echo "+cpu" > /cgroups/cgroup.subtree_control
echo "+memory" > /cgroups/cgroup.subtree_control

cat $PLISTFILE | while read ROW ; do
  USERNAME=$(echo "$ROW" | cut -d' ' -f1)
  PROCESSID=$(echo "$ROW" | cut -d' ' -f2)
  echo $PROCESSID > /cgroups/$USERNAME/cgroup.procs  
done
```